# How to use IWBootstrap4 component in Delphi intraweb?

Tags: delphi, intraweb

Anybody knows how IWBootstrap4 works. they look promising but I couldn't find anything online say how to use them, any idea?

[image]

For example I know how to integrate bootstrap with intraweb using templates but how to utilize those stuff? I thought it might be the same way, but it didn't work, so is there another approach to use them?

I tried to use them directly -> new form -> add them but nothing works.

any idea how to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully used BS4 components. Just add bootstrap js and css to ServerController.HTMLHeaders or to form ExtraHeader: something like

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Drop a component on form and in its css property you can use bs styles (e.g.: d-flex flex-column ms-2 me-2). Or, in style property, you can enter css properties (e.g. width: 300px background-color: green).